# Window Only Renders correctly on first show

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I have a window that I am opening like so

```
if (Window == null) {
    var con = WindowType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    Window = (PopupWindow)con.Invoke(new object[0]);
    //The types are subclasses of PopupWindow.
    Window.Controller = this;
    Window.Show ();
}
```

This correctly displays the window as long as it is the first of these windows to pop up... If I close the window and create an entirely new one, the window is just a grey area until I restart debugging... Any ideas?

```
public PopupWindow () : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    this.AppPaintable = true;
    this.Colormap = this.Screen.RgbaColormap;
    this.Events = Gdk.EventMask.AllEventsMask;
    this.Decorated = false;
    this.SkipTaskbarHint = true;
}
```

Example subclass

```
public StorageWindow () : base()
{
    this.Build ();
    this.Move (this.Screen.Width - 428, 55);
    //set some label props.

    StorageCircle.ExposeEvent += (o, args) => {
        //Draw a circle
    };

}
```

P.S. This is how I am destroying the window.

```
if (Window != null) {
    Window.Destroy();
    Window = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire issue turned out to be caused by a non gtk timer trying to edit widgets outside of the main thread.